# Inconsistency in application of the increment operator when used in expressions

Tags: javascript, semantics

In JavaScript we have postfix (x++) and prefix  (++x)increment like many other C derivative syntax. I know that both prefix and postfix increment has a higher precedence than addition.

So if we do the following,  y gets the value 2, as  x (as 1) gets added to x (as 1) and then x gets incremented to 2.

```
x = 1
y = x + x++
```

However, if then I do the following y gets the value 3. Why is it not 2 like the other example? Or conversely, why is the other example giving 2 if the rules of precedence are being obeyed?

```
x = 1
y = x++ + x
```

Another example of where you can see this is in the following examples:

In this example y has the value 4. But really what is going on here semantically? I guess because its assign and then increment, the x first represents 1 so we have 1 + 1, then its incremented, and next we add it to x (which is now 2) making 4.

```
x = 1
y = x + x++ + x
```

But, then we have an inconsistency. Take a look at the following, what is semantically going on here? The result I got in y was 5, and not 6 like I expected.

```
x = 1
y = x + ++x + x
```

Here is my take what I think should be happening First x++ is evaluated incrementing x to 2, then this is added to the first x (which is now 2) making 4, this value should then be added to the second x making 6. But, that is not what happens Y gets 5 when I try this in the REPL.

Why is it 5?

Comment: It's not about operator precedence, rather order of evaluation

Comment: Tell me more about that?

Comment: Operator precedence is about how an otherwise ambiguous expression is parsed, i.e. `x + y * z` is `x + (y * z)` not `(x + y) * z` because `*` has higher precedence than `+`. But it doesn't say in which order the parts will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is strictly evaluated left-to-right. That means the left operand of `+` is evaluated before its right operand.

- If the left-hand side expression changes `x`, this change will already be visible when the right-hand side is evaluated
- If the right-hand side expression changes `x`, this change happens only after the left-hand side was evaluated

So for your examples, we have the step-by-step evaluations

```
y = x + x++ // x: 1
y = 1 + x++ // x: 1
y = 1 + 1 // x: 2
y = 2 // x: 2

y = x++ + x // x: 1
y = 1 + x // x: 2
y = 1 + 2 // x: 2
y = 3 // x: 2

y = x + x++ + x // x: 1
y = 1 + x++ + x // x: 1
y = 1 + 1 + x // x: 2
y = 2 + x // x: 2
y = 2 + 2 // x: 2
y = 4 // x: 2

y = x + ++x + x // x: 1
y = 1 + ++x + x // x: 1
y = 1 + 2 + x // x: 2
y = 3 + x // x: 2
y = 3 + 2 // x: 2
y = 5 // x: 2

y = x + ++x * x // x: 1
y = 1 + ++x * x // x: 1
y = 1 + 2 * x // x: 2
y = 1 + 2 * 2 // x: 2
y = 1 + 4 // x: 2
y = 5 // x: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear. Could you provide an additional example that uses addition, multiplication and increment?  I feel this would really show the how the operator precedence and evaluation order  are applied within the same expression.

Comment: I think this (excellent) explanation give ample reason to _not_ use mutating operators — and arguably not use mutable variables at all!

Comment: @AndrewS Regardless whether you do `(x + y) * z`, `x * y + z`, `x + y * z` or `x + (y * z)`, it's always `x` being evaluated first, `y` second, and `z` third; then the arithmetic result is computed. (Replace `x`, `y` and `z` with any expressions, like function calls, that affect the other expressions or not, the order doesn't change)

Comment: @MichaelLorton Well at least in JS you know what it'll do (and you cannot always avoid mutation). Other languages don't even give that guarantee…

Comment: @Bergi So, JavaScript it determines the values of variables left to right (and I presume function calls too), and then applies the order of operations? Or does it do this only at the sub expression level i.e. <operand> <operator> <operand>?

Comment: A good example here would be: x = 1;  y = x + ++x  * x;

Comment: @AndrewS Evaluation is top-down, so the outermost operation is first to evaluate its operands (left-to-right), and during that operand evaluation the inner operations are evaluated recursively.

Comment: This does leave one question hanging. Why does the post-icrimental operator have higher operator precedence than the numerical operators / , * . , %, + and - ?

Comment: Because it's not possible to increment (assign to) the result of a numerical operation. It needs to assign to a variable or property reference.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix `++` increment will return the original value before incrementing immediately after. As JavaScript is evaluated left to right, any value after the increment would have been incremented.

Below is what your `x++ + x` statement evaluates to:

`1 + 2`

`x++` returns 1, then increments by one causing the following `x` to be `2`.